# В каком порядке интерфейсы выводятся в команде ipconfig?

Tags: windows, сеть, интерфейс

При использовании в Windows ipconfig или ipconfig /all, в каком порядке выводятся интерфейсы? У меня есть два интерфейса:  "Ethernet 1" и  "Ethernet 3". Но почему-то первым выводится третий, и он является виртуальным, для openvpn. Мне нужно, чтобы в ipconfig и в иных программах, определяющих список интерфейсов, первым по порядку шёл физический интерфейс "Ethernet 1", по которому у меня приходит LAN. Как это сделать?
Изначально у 3 был мак-адрес меньше, чем у 1, я поменял его, но это не возымело эффекта. В реестре по адресу HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318} сетевое устройство, связанное с данным интерфейсом находится на последнем месте.

Comment: *Как это сделать?* Никак. ОС инициализирует интерфейсы как захочет, и выводит в том порядке, в каком пронумеровала. Не нравится, нужен определённый порядок - сортируйте вывод.

Comment: @Akina, да не, я уже разобрался. Если вручную выставить метрику интерфейсов, то как раз выходит то что надо. Выше метрика — ниже по списку выходит интерфейс. Во всяком случае в ipconfig.

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашлось в метрике интерфейса. Свойства - IPv4 - Свойства - Дополнительно - внизу выставил метрики, и по ним упорядочилось.

Comment: Менять метрику интерфейса ради порядка вывода? да вы эстет... впрочем, если устраивает, то и ладно.

Comment: @Akina, если бы я знал иное решение, то воспользовался бы им.

Comment: Я просто привык, что если позиционность возврата данных начинает иметь значение и влиять на конечный результат, то что-то неладно в алгоритме обработки. так что не обращайте внимания на моё бухтение...

Comment: @ Akina, вы правы, но не всегда есть возможность поменять тот алгоритм. Я вижу лишь логи действий программы, что она находит интерфейсы в определённом порядке, но поменять ничего не могу.

Answer (score 0):

У меня метрика не повлияла на порядок вывода интерфейсов.
Однако, как оказалось, в винде есть уже встроенный способ изменения порядка NICs

Нашел тут

https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/Change-the-binding-order-of-Network-Adapters

`Запускаем ncpa.cpl
В меню Organize/Layout включаем Menu bar.
В меню Advanced заходим Advanced Settings
В закладке Adapters and Bindings меняем порядок NIC`

[image: Change the binding order of Network Adapters]